# display button at the very bottom of the screen and right side

Tags: android

How to display image button at the very bottom of the screen and right side.
Right now, i am using like this, but button is not showing at the very bottom of the screen.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibdGoBack"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/back_button"
    android:contentDescription="@string/backbutton" />
```

there is only one textview on the screen.

Comment: alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: I would check `ImageButton`'s parent Layout. For example, is it a RelativeLayout? then alignParentBottom="true" is what you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibdGoBack"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backbutton"  />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Or LinearLayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="bottom|right">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibdGoBack"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backbutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If container view is `LinearLayout` then it should have worked fine.
I hope it is `RelativeLayout` and want you to try this.

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ibdGoBack"
android:layout_width="42dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
android:background="@drawable/back_button"
android:contentDescription="@string/backbutton"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: @Jeeten Parmar please post the entire xml of your layout so that we can sort this out.

Comment: container view i LinearLayout and it is not working. I changed it to RelativeLayout and then assign alignParentBottom and alignPatenRight, then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which is the parent `viewgroup` of the `imagebutton`, but it might work for you if you use `relativelayout` as its parent (or root) and use `alignParentBottom="true"` and `alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Check this layout

```
 <RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </RelativeLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

For bottom and right side, use this simple code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```